# Under what circumstances could Photos delete a large number of albums without warning or indication?

Tags: icloud, photos.app

This morning, I had ~4500 photos, all in Photos albums. All had been uploaded to iCloud in the last couple of days, and were represented correctly across multiple devices. There was no further iCloud activity taking place.

At some point between then and this evening Photos has, without any warning that it would or had, deleted a very large number of those albums. There are now ~2500 photos not in any album. All the photos seem still seem to be in the library, but albums are gone (on iCloud, and across multiple devices).

How is this possible?

Albums are affected randomly, there appears to be no pattern to it.

I haven't been editing photos or albums since this morning.

I suspect that it's some kind of database conflict in iCloud, that it resolved by deleting these items.

I did turn on an old iPad (iOS 9.3.5) this afternoon, that's connected to my iCloud account, and opened Photos. Conceivably that's somehow related, but it was already connected to the account.

I have a TimeMachine backup, but it's hard to guess how an old Photos library database is going to interact with iCloud.

---

I completely wiped the iPad I mentioned since writing the above - a complete reset - and allowed it to reconnect to the account.

I watched the photos and albums appearing as it downloaded the library. After a while, some of the *missing* albums appeared on the iPad, in their expected places.

The same albums were not showing up on icloud.com, the source that it was downloading them from.

And then a few minutes later on the iPad, again before my eyes, I watched them disappear again, popping out of existence.

I still see *some* of the "missing" albums showing up on the iPad, downloaded in the last minutes, though they're not visible via icloud.com - oh, but they are now: *literally* while typing this sentence, they deigned to appear.

Will they remain? Will they disappear again? Who knows?

I will leave this car-crash of software overnight and see what's left in the wreckage in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

There's no intended circumstance where Photos on its own initiative deletes a large number of albums without warning or indication.

What you're seeing is most likely a bug or at least a configuration issue. It could be a bug in the iCloud server software, or it could be a bug in Photos - most likely in the old iOS 9 unit then.

There's a chance that something got "corrupted" on a local device and that synchronized to the other devices and messed up your albums. For example if the clock has been off on one device (the iOS 9 one), it might be that an iPhoto library without albums would have been seen as "newer" than other ones where you had already created the albums - and that "newer" state then got synchronized on top of the others.

Comment: Thanks, the question of the clock is interesting, one that I hadn't considered. Since my first update above, though, I have seen more albums reappear - but *only* on the iPad, not even on iCloud.com/photos, and not on the other devices, including the one that was the original source of them all. Even so, the iPad still does not contain all the albums. On this basis I'm inclined to shift blame from the iPad after all.